# get value of textbox from a another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a c# windows application that contains a menu and a dock panel. if click on any element on the menu, a form appears on the dock panel

there is a book form that contains search textbox.

in the menu there is an item with name (save) used to save the layout for other use, and the opened forms still opens in the dock panel as tabs after saving the layout

note: user can open the same form several times

---

what i need is, when the user click on the save link, i need to get the value of the search textbox from book form and set it in a variable in the main form.

---

any help?

Comment: WinForms or WPF? What model? Can we see some code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> texts = new List<String>();
foreach(Form form in Application.OpenForms){
    if (form.Name == "bookForm"){
        TextBox textbox= form.Controls[<your textbox namr>] as TextBox;
        texts.Add(textbox);
    }
}
```

then you can use this texts list as you can

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property that acts as a wrapper for the search textbox's `Text` property.

```
public string SearchString
{
    get {
        return searchTextbox.Text; // Where the searchTextbox is id of the textbox
    }
}
```

This can then be referenced on the instance of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function on your main form to set the value for the variable:

```
private void My_method(string value)
    {        
        your_variable = value;              
    }
```

Now while opening your BookForm pass the main form as a parameter to the Book Form constructor like this

```
Main_Form _fd;
public BookForm(Main_form fd)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _fd = fd;
    }
```

Now you can call the Mainform function from anywhere on this form like :-

```
_fd.My_method(searchtextBox.text);
```

Now user don't have to open and close the form again and again ! Hope it will help you !

Comment: this doesn't match since the user can open book form several times at the same time

Comment: @danny-london - what do you mean by same form in your question? Book form or Main form?
And you are saying that user can open the same form in more than 1 instance ?

Comment: i mean that the user can open more than one book form in the main form